System broadcasts RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED while receiving otp
Dart Version: ">=2.19.4 <3.0.0"
firebase_core: ^2.15.1
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.6
flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0+1
java.lang.SecurityException: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
android:exported="true" is set in AndroidManifest.xml
The app is crashing in the verify otp screen.
Please let me kown if I need to provide any more information.
I tried to upgrade the version of firebase_core and firebase_messaging.
I am receiving the error in Android 14 and not in Android 12(Go Edition).

I had the same issue once I upgraded the min-sdk version to 34. I had to search which package were using the stream broadcast in the specific page. Turns out the package 'pinput' had an issue and was fixed once I upgraded the package version.
Here's a ticket related to it: As demanded by Google, since I moved to `targetSdkVersion` 34 (from 33) , my app crashes
